# Weird results with movzwl, %ax and negative values

Tags: assembly, x86, sign-extension, zero-extension

Alright, so I am dealing with the following snippet of code:

```
push   %ebp
mov    %esp,%ebp   
push   %ebx
mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax 
movzwl %ax,%edx
```

So this behaves as expected when dealing with positive values. The value copied into %edx is the trailing 16 bits of %eax (or %ax).

However, if you put a negative number in, everything starts getting weird and it does not seem to be behaving as expected.

For example, if the value of %eax is -67043552, then the value copied into %edx is 65312.

I'm fairly new to assembly, sorry if this is an obvious misinterpretation on my part. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`movswl`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSX:MOVSXD.html) is available when you want to sign-extend a 2's complement signed value instead of zero-extending a binary unsigned value.  (See also the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Comment: Also, if you printed your numbers as hex, it would be a lot less confusing / more obvious what's going on.

Comment: Also, unless you actually need the full value in `%eax`, you should `movzwl   0x8(%ebp), %edx` directly instead of wasting an instruction doing it separately.  Intel CPUs can handle `movzx` / `movsx` as just a load uop, with no ALU required.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remember that `movzwl` copies only the bits in `%ax` into `%edx` filling in the high 16 bits of `%edx` with zeros.

So `%edx` always ends up with a positive number less than or equal to 65535.

In detail: `-67043552` in hex is `fc00ff20`.  So if that is in `%eax`, then `%ax` contains `ff20`.  If you move that into `%edx` with zero-extension, then `%edx` gets `0000ff20`.  That's 65312.